# Неправильная сумма элементов матрицы

Tags: c++, матрицы

Написал программу,которая переставляет столбцы в соответствии с ростом характеристик,но почему-то неправильно считается сумма элементов столбца,в котором есть хоть один отрицательный элемент.В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    srand((int)time(0));
    int n, m;
    cout << "Введите количество строк "; cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов "; cin >> m;
    
        int **a = new int*[n];
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
          a[i]=new int[m];
  
        int *c = new int[m]();
      
    cout <<"Matrix a:\n";  
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=rand()%19 - 9;        
            cout << setw(3) << a[i][j] << " ";    
        }               
        cout << "\n";
    }    
    
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {        
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
            if(a[i][j]<0 && a[i][j]%2!=0) c[j]+=abs(a[i][j]);            
       cout << "col " << j+1 << ":  sum=" << c[j] << "\n";
    }      
    
    for (int j = 1; j < m; j++)    
        for (int k = 0; k < m-j; k++)        
            if (c[k]>c[k+1])
            {
                swap(c[k],c[k+1]); 
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                swap(a[i][k],a[i][k+1]);
            } 
           
    cout <<"\nSorted matrix a:\n";        
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)        
            cout << setw(3) << a[i][j] << " ";       
        cout <<"\n";
    }    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    delete[]a[i];
    delete[]a;
    delete[]c;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Добавляю результат программы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Четче можете написать условие задачи пожалуйста? Я запустил у себя и вроде все работает. Если я правильно понял, вам нужно в столбце в котором есть хотя бы один отрицательный элемент, посчитать сумму? А что делать с теми столбцами в которых нет отрицательного элемента?

Comment: Ничего,для столбцов отрицательными элементами вывести сумму,а для тех,в которых нет не выводить

Comment: Можете привести пример входных данных, где вы считаете что сумма неправильно считается? Прям вопрос дополните матрицей небольшой (3 на 3) где по вашему сумма считается неправильно.

Comment: Удалите свой ответ и примите лучше мою правку, я внес скрин с результатами в вопрос. И все же, что делать со столбцом где нет отрицательных чисел во время сортировки? Его на месте оставить?

Answer (score 2):

1. Вы добавляете не сам элемент, а его модуль `c[j] += abs(a[i][j]`
2. Вы складываете только нечетные элементы: `if (a[i][j]<0 && a[i][j]%2!=0)`

Для того, чтобы получить сумму столбца, в котором содержится хоть один отрицательный элемент нужно:

1. Проверить, есть ли в столбце отр. элемент
2. Прибавить каждый его элемент.

```
...
bool* is_negative = new bool[m]; // True - есть, False - нет отр. элемент
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
    for(int j=0; j<m; ++j){
        is_negative[j] = false;
        if(a[i][j] < 0){
            is_negative[j] = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

for(int j=0; j<m; ++j)
    if(is_negative[j])
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            c[j] += a[i][j];
```

Comment: Этот кусок следует вставить сразу после заполнения массива? Или куда еще?

Comment: @SmetanaPoAktsii, да, вместо вашего цикла суммирования